# List view does not show up options on click of triple dot

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-pages, context-menu

I have a list and I have added that list in a Modern page through the List Web part available (OOTB functionality).
If I directly go to List view through the `site contents` > `List` > `select any list item's triple dot` > then I can see multiple options in the context menu such as "Open", "Version History", "Manage Access" etc.
But when I navigate to the Modern page and go to the list section where it displays the list item, click on the triple dot of any of the selected item, it only displays only three options

1."Delete",

2."Link to item" and

3."Share".

It does not displays other options, as mentioned above.

It is happening with any user, even site administrators are also having the same issue.

Kindly help me on this to proceed further.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, this is a correct phenomenon in SharePoint, it is by design.

[image]

You can use **Embed Web Part** to add a list to the page.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
If we use embed web part, it actually displays the whole webpage including the list view within the web part section, which is what client does not want.